Find offset for a point on a bezier curve for follow path constraint
I want to find the offset values for all the points on a bezier curve so that I can precisely animate an object that is following path on this curve. For example in the screenshot below I have bezier curve with 3 points and I want to know what offset value will lead me exactly at point 1 and 2 (3 in this case will be at an offset of 1.00).
I want to be able to do this using python since I have a lot of curves with a lot of points and I can't do it manually for all. Through some research I was able to figure out an approach and it seems to be working but not perfectly. The code below works sort of fine for the first point but then the offsets become increasingly incorrect for any subsequent points. Code:
import math
from mathutils import Vector

# Function to calculate the distance between two points
def calculate_distance(point1, point2):
    return (point1 - point2).length

# Get the curve object and its evaluated state
curve_obj = bpy.data.objects['Curve']
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
curve_eval = curve_obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)

# Get the evaluated curve data from the evaluated object
curve_data = curve_eval.data
spline = curve_data.splines[0]  # Assuming a single spline in the curve

# Number of points to sample along the curve
num_samples = 100

# List to store positions and distances
curve_positions = []
distances = []

# Sample the curve geometry more accurately along the curve length
for i in range(num_samples + 1):  # Include both endpoints
    t = i / num_samples  # Normalized parameter from 0.0 to 1.0
    
    # Use the correct curve modifier method to sample the curve
    point = curve_obj.matrix_world @ spline.bezier_points[0].co.lerp(spline.bezier_points[-1].co, t)
    
    curve_positions.append(point)
    
    # Calculate the distance between consecutive points
    if i > 0:
        distance = calculate_distance(curve_positions[i], curve_positions[i-1])
        distances.append(distance)

# Calculate cumulative distances
cumulative_distances = [0]  # Start with 0 for the first point
for d in distances:
    cumulative_distances.append(cumulative_distances[-1] + d)

# Normalize distances to a range between 0 and 1
total_length = cumulative_distances[-1]
normalized_distances = [dist / total_length for dist in cumulative_distances]

# Ensure sphere movement is precise based on distance and frame mapping
sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
follow_path_constraint = sphere.constraints['Follow Path']

# Example: Ensure keyframes align to desired points along the curve
# Map these frames correctly based on curve distances
frame_targets = [1, 25, 50, 75]  # Adjust these frames as needed for accuracy

# Animate the 'offset_factor' property based on normalized distances
for i, frame in enumerate(frame_targets):
    distance = normalized_distances[int(i * num_samples / (len(frame_targets)-1))]
    
    follow_path_constraint.offset_factor = distance
    follow_path_constraint.keyframe_insert(data_path="offset_factor", frame=frame)

# Print normalized distances to verify
print("Normalized distances along the curve:", normalized_distances)

